# SQL Statement to set NULL Values to initialized values

Tags: sql, t-sql, null, initialization

In SQL or T-SQL how can I go through a table and set fields that are NULL to empty strings if the type is textual and 0 if the fields are integer types.

Thanks for any help, I do not even know where to begin.

Comment: Do you know the table, columns, column data types ahead of time? Do the columns need to be changed to prevent nulls from being entered in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're suggesting would only work as a "one off".

If you always want those fields to be populated going forward you can set a default value on the table.

Answer (score 3):

Well if it's just one table use a basic update query:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET NumericColumn = ISNULL(NumericColumn,0), 
StringColumn= ISNULL(StringColumn,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsNull function in T-SQL,

Syntax :

```
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `coalesce( expression_1 , expression_2 , ... )` is also useful in this context.

It evaluates the specified expressions from left to right and returns the value of the first expression that evaluates to a value other than `null`, or `null` if all the specified expressions evaluate to `null`.

This can be useful, especially in conjunction with left joins and table rotations.